# in whole process i need to try enter n no. of questions and n no. of choices are save in mongoshell

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

**1. schema code**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let presenterschema = new Schema({
    Name: String,
    Organization: String,
    Email: String,
    phone: Number,
    question: [{
        question: String,
        choice: [{
            choice_a: String,
            choice_b: String,
            choice_c: String,
            choice_d: String,
        }],
    }],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('presenter', presenterschema);
```

**Email using as unique keyword to find out those email address which was already in db and push question and choices to that email id.**

**1. node.js code**

```
app.post('/get_questio', function (req, res) {
    presenter.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, function (err, data) {
        question = req.body.question;
        choice = req.body.choice;
        choice_a = req.body.choice_a;
        choice_b = req.body.choice_b;
        choice_c = req.body.choice_c;
        choice_d = req.body.choice_d;
        data.question.push({ question })
        data.question.choice.push({ choice_a, choice_b, choice_c, choice_d })

        data.save(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("something went wrong " + err)
            } else {
                res.send(data)
            }

        })
    })
})
```

**actual i tried create a quiz application.**

Comment: what the error you are getting?

Comment: choices array is blank.

 {
   "question" : "what is square circumfrence 55 ?",
   "_id" : ObjectId("58b80c27db205d2ead173e8d"),
   "choice" : [ ]
  },

Comment: i get blank array when i post my api